# Let be $\varphi$ and $\psi$ linear transformations in $\mathbb{R}^2$ Which well known linear transformation will be $\varphi \psi$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$\varphi= \mu_{A}$ where 
$
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   1 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$
and $\psi$ is the orthogonal projection to the y axis.

So I'm searching in the first step for the matrix of the projection to the y axis. If I project the point $(1,1)$ to the y axis I get, $(0,1)$ in a general case, if I project to $(x,y)$ point to the y axis I get, $(0,y)$ In the next step I have to make the matrix multiplication of $
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   1 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ $ \times [0,y]$ which gives me again $[0,y]$, so is the linear transformation $\psi$? I'm not sure about that my solution is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Let $x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$ be any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We can then write

$$\psi(x)=e_2\cdot x=\begin{bmatrix}0\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$$

We will then have

$$\varphi\psi(x)=\varphi(\psi(x))=A\psi(x)=A\begin{bmatrix}0\\x_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\x_2\end{bmatrix}=\psi(x)$$

If you want a more intuitive "proof", examine what these functions are doing in more detail. $\psi$ is an orthogonal projection to the $y$-axis, so $\psi(x)$ will only have a $y$ component and thus lay on the $y$-axis. Now, examine the matrix $A$. Note that that $y$-axis is invariant under transformation by $A$. Naturally, this implies that $\psi$  will be invariant under transformation by $A$. That is, $\varphi\psi=A\psi=\psi$.